# Online resources for airplane seat sizes

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, seating

Are there online resources for researching seat sizes and leg room of various planes of various airlines?

I'd like to know whether JAL international flight economy class seats are [small](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4174/324) (compared to a Virgin Australia domestic economy class seat), or whether I'm just imagining it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure! There's [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/).

The only issue is you'll need to know what plane you were on, as the configuration often changes depending on the plane and length of flight for each airline.

So have a look at the stats for [JAL on SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Japan_Airlines/fleetinfo.php) and for [Virgin Australia on SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Virgin_Australia/fleetinfo.php), and you'll see that the JAL ones range from 16.5" to 18" across, while the Virgin ones range from 17 to 18.8" across, depending on which aircraft you were on.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are imagining it. Flying on both Virgin Atlantic and JAL from Europe to Japan, JAL's seats are much bigger. About the same width, but much more leg room. Their advertising claims an extra 10cm of leg room over the average, and my knees are certainly better off on JAL.

https://www.jal.co.jp/en/newsky/ss7/economy/seat/